# React router Link with 'to' prop as object is not rendering correct component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have simple app with react-router v5. In App component I have switch like this:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/post">
    <Post />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*">
    <Error />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

In other component I have Link with path like this:

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: `/post?id=${message.id}`, state: { message } }}>text</Link>
```

Now, Error component is only logging the pathname and state from useLocation() hook, Post component is showing pathname in HTML tag.

When I click the link, the component that is rendered, is 'Error', it console.log correct path name ('.post?id=123'), and it logs correct state. Address in browser is correct, but Post component is not rendered. When I refresh browser, then correct component is rendered. I mean when i refresh being on post?id=123, then 'Post' is rendered, but when I try to click link directing to 'post?id=123', 'Error' is rendered. If I use <Link to={`/post?id=${message.id}` /> without state, routing is working fine.

Here's [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-boyd-4d16j), it seems the issue is this part: to={{pathname: '/post?id=${message.id}, state: {message}}, when I remove ?id=${...} it works fine. But still I would like to have this id there.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example that covers `Post`, `Error`, and the components rendering the `Router`/`Switch` components and the `Link`? Also including a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we could debug would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I shouldn't use query string when using object as 'to' parameter. If someone needs to include query string, there is search parameter in 'to' object.